# Rails Memory leak using highChart with a lot of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, highcharts, memory-leaks

I hava a highchart graphic in one of my views and an option to select a a range of dates to query and show in the graphic. The think is when I perform a query with a big date range (e.g. a year range), the memory goes up and it never goes back to a normal state and finally I need to reset the server...
The view calls a class method that performs the query and return the array of data to create the graphic. The method initially was this:

```
data = []

  messages.each do |message|
    record = []
    record << message.occurance_time.to_s(:highcharts_format)
    record << weight_according_to_metric(message.weight, us_metric_enabled)
    record << temperature_according_to_metric(message.temperature, us_metric_enabled)
    record << (message.humidity.nil? ? nil : message.humidity.to_f)
    data << record
  end
```

but after some tests I put *find_each* instead of *.each* and I wrapped the loop inside a **ActiveRecord::Base.uncached** statment:

```
data = []
ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
  messages.find_each do |message|
    record = []
    record << message.occurance_time.to_s(:highcharts_format)
    record << weight_according_to_metric(message.weight, us_metric_enabled)
    record << temperature_according_to_metric(message.temperature, us_metric_enabled)
    record << (message.humidity.nil? ? nil : message.humidity.to_f)
    data << record
  end
end
```

But I'm still having memory issues. It is obvious that while the queries are being executed the memory goes up, but why is not the memory going down after the query and graphic creation?

It's running with puma on Heroku!

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't believe the issue has to to with ActiveRecord's caching, I believe it could be related to the gems that you are using.  The uncached block in your statement above won't buy you anything IMHO

Comment: Anyway, with or without uncached block, my memory is always kept high after the graphic creation...

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Comment: It's running on Puma and is on Heroku!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been several reports of memory leaks associated with puma and ruby 2.1 and 2.2. The ruby garbage collector has experienced quite a bit of changes from 2.0 to 2.2: Generational GC in [2.1](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/12/25/ruby-2-1-0-is-released/), Incremental GC in [2.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/12/25/ruby-2-2-0-released/).

Leaks reported:

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/342

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/978

I noticed a similar issue as you described after upgrading from Ruby 2.0 to 2.2. After several fruitless days of research and testing, I finally moved to the latest stable Ruby [2.3.1], Rails [4.2.6], and puma [3.4.0] releases. The leak disappeared.